# How to copy data to other MySQL server

Tags: mysql, database-migration

I've to make a copy of a database to another (both are MySQL databases and almost have the same schema). The problem is that there are many relationships between the tables and I've to change almost all of the primary keys (tables have one primary key, an id column) mantaining the relationships. What approach or tool could I use to achieve it?

Thanks for all and sorry for my english.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in this? I'd move the data first, then do the `ALTER TABLE` commands on the new database.

Comment: @ceejayoz I want to move the data but with new primary keys mantaining the relationships. I haven't any experience doing this, so I've no idea about how to start.

Comment: Have you tried Google???

Comment: if you don't care about the data on db 2, then i'd just do a backup of db 1, then import it over db 2.

Comment: Hi @Napoli. I can´t do that because in the destination database I've different data with the same primary keys as in the source database.